# Filtering inside a cell templates?

Tags: angular-ui-grid, ng-grid, ui-grid

I have the following cell template 
cellTemplate: {{COL_FIELD | row. entity. filter}}

But the filers is not working.  If am passing directly as string in the template it's working.  But in my case the filers are dynamic.

Can any one help

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass a variable as a filter, because Angular will look for the filter name as 'row.entity.filter' rather than the real value you expected.

You can pass Angular pre-defined filter like number or you custom filter in the cell template like:

```
{{COL_FIELD | number:3}}

{{COL_FIELD | customerFilter}}
```